# Object without any content/empty Object

Tags: java, list, collections, dictionary, set

while developing I was trying to return an empty *List*.

```
public Collection<?> getElements() {
    // return elements
}
```

I searched for an easy way, my first idea was to create for example an *ArrayList* without any elements and return it. Like the following example:

```
public Collection<?> getElements() {
    return new ArrayList<?>();
}
```

For me it is too much overhead for an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really simple solution for the above described "problem":

```
public Collection<?> getElements() {
    return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

That returns an empty list.

**Notice:**
It returns an **immutable** object! You can use it only, if you need an object, which isn't editable.

**Type-safety**
In the case you want to get a type-safe list you should use the following example [[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29)]:

```
List<String> s = Collections.emptyList();
```

Three kinds of interfaces are supported:

- *List*:

  ```
  List l = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
  List<String> s = Collections.emptyList();
  ```
- *Map*:

  ```
  Map m = Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
  Map<String> ms = Collections.emptyMap();
  ```
- *Set*:

  ```
  Set s = Collections.EMPTY_SET;
  Set<String> ss = Collections.emptySet();
  ```

**Notice:**

> Implementations of this method need not create a separate XXX object
>   for each call. Using this method is likely to have comparable cost to
>   using the like-named field. (Unlike this method, the field does not
>   provide type safety.)

Comment: +1 Maybe worth noting that the returned collection is immutable, so the calling code won't be able to add to the list.

Comment: There are a lot of times when I need that code. :) That was the reason why I post that. But I will add it, thanks.

Comment: Why are you answering your own problem without waiting anyone to answer also ?

Comment: Everyone is free to add an own answer. ;) I have no problem with sharing my knowledge, which can help someone else in the future. There is the possibility given by stackoverflow, why don't use it?

Comment: I really don't understand the goal of this question, if you already have the answer. Or is it to earn some score?

Comment: Yes I know that, but for this you need to have a real problem. IMO you don't need to create such a question just to explain how to use something as simple as `Collections.emptyList()` there is Javadoc for that.

Comment: I didn't known it before, so I just want to point on it. For discussing start a chat with me, please.

Comment: You can accept it (after two days). How I tried to express before, if someone else has a better answer, I have no problems with accepting that one.